# Angular 4 - How to calculate price based on change in quantity and option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Requirement** 
There are a list of items in the shopping cart. Each item has option, quantity, price. Need to calculate the price based on change in quantity and option of a item.

**Research**
I had added [(ngModel)] as below, so as to use 2 way data-binding, however, no idea why the page simply keeps on loading and than crashes without any error.
When i remove the ngModel attribute the page loads successfully.

```
<span class="price col-1 pull-right" >{{ orderType*price}}</span>
<div class="qty" style="margin:0;">
     <span class="spinner">
        <span class="sub">-</span>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" min="1" max="100" 
               value="1" class="qty-spinner" [(ngModel)]="quantity" />
        <span class="add">+</span>
     </span>
 </div>
 <div class="type">
     <label class="radio inline" *ngFor="let option of item.options; let k = index"> 
     <input id="{{'toggle-half-'+item.id+'-'+j}}" type="radio" 
            name="{{'option-toggle-'+item.id+'-'+j}}" [value]="option.value" 
            [checked]='k===0' [(ngModel)]="orderType" />
     <span>{{option.title}} </span> 
     </label>
 </div>
```

**TypeScript Code**

```
quantity:number;
orderType:number;
price:number;

constructor() {
    this.quantity = 1;
    this.price = 0;
}
```

**Controls used** 
1) Number Control **input of type number** for quantity. 
2) Radio Control for Options [Half/Full] 
3) span element for printing calculated price.

**Expected Output**

Price which is currently set to 0 should get updated when we change the quantity or the option.

Eg. Value set for option [**Half**] = 10

Eg. Value set for option [**Full**] = 20

Please advise how can i implement this, is the above logic and implmentation correct ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually when Angular fails silently is due to syntax errors at the HTML

Comment: Hi, i went through some examples and videos as well, and this was the syntax [(ngModel)]="<property>"

Comment: What is `option.value`: numbers, strings? 0, 1, 2 like an index? 'Half', 'Full' or 0.5, 1?

Comment: there are 2 options, half and full for each item in the list.
Each option [Half=10 and Full=20] has a value that is the actual value of the product.
Output html elements would be like this :
<input type="radio" value="10">Half
<input type="radio" value="20">Full

Answer (score 0):

The variable `option` is already in use in the `ngFor` directive. See line:

`<label class="radio inline" *ngFor="let option of item.options; let k = index">`

Use a different variable instead for the `ngModel`, example:

```
<input id="{{'toggle-half-'+item.id+'-'+j}}"  
       type="radio" 
       name="{{'option-toggle-'+item.id+'-'+j}}" 
       [value]="option.value"
       [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" />
```

Look at the examples in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-form-directives);

**EDIT**

Also you have you're binding the `checked` attribute while imposing a `ngModel`. Instead of doing that, simply init the `ngModel` with the value you want, in your case,

`selectedOption = item.options[0].value`

Comment: Apologies, i did change it to a different one and updated the description, but still the same behaviour

Comment: Made an update, try removing `[checked]` and see my changes on how to set a default. does it still crash?

Comment: item is a list of items and each item has options. hence, item.options[0].value won't work. I implemented the way you suggested removed the checked attribute, however, still the page it keeps on loading

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* Reviewing the documentation sample shared in jkris' answer, `value` makes sense for radio inputs. I still suspect `checked` creates an update loop when combined with `[(ngModel)]`.

---

I notice you're binding `checked` in addition to the NgModel binding. If you remove it, does it keep the correct behavior and prevent crashing?

```
<input type="number" class="qty-spinner" min="1" max="100" 
       name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="quantity" />


<input type="radio" 
       [value]="option.value" name="option" [(ngModel)]="option" />
```

Otherwise, another option is to use `[checked]` and `(click)`(or similar) bindings in place of NgModel.

Comment: I removed the checked attribute, however, no luck. i did remove the whole input radio element, but still the same issue, then i removed the ngModel from input type number element, and then the page loaded successfully. Something unexpected with the property i guess

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it crashed but if i were you. The constructor

```
constructor() {
    this.quantity = 1;
    this.price = 0;
}
```

I will use ngInit instead since its a two way binding.

```
     import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

        export class myClas implements OnInit {

        ngOnInit() {
            this.quantity = 1;
            this.price = 0;
        }

    }
```

Secondly, you have value in your radio button and input type number. Are you sure they return value of type number ? If i were you i will use or try string first and cast it to my desired number type afterward. Or use a pipe. Wrong type conversion can be expensive sometimes . So  can you try

```
quantity:string;
orderType:string;
price:string;
```

first and do your number conversion afterward ?

Comment: sure. i did try placing the initialization in ngOnInit() as well, however, no luck, will try with changing type to string...

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resolved now.
The code snippet in the description was implemented between a div tag which had a *ngFor directive, that iterated through the list of items.

**Issue** 
For dividing the list of items into 2 columns "div.col-md-6", i had implemented a a function that returned me an array of 2 arrays each containing set of items, so as to iterate through each array and display the items in each column.

Could not find the issue, why there was an issue only when i implemented the ngModel tag, which should have not been the case. However, i removed that splitting function and everything worked fine for me.

Thanks to all for your efforts and help.